# Oracle iteration and collections

Tags: oracle, plsql

How I can iterate over loop and collect information inside variable/collection?

Something like:

```
cursor cursor_c= select col1 from table1 where condition;
collection l;
foreach row in cursor_c
  l.add (select col2 from table2 where col1=row);
end;
printout(l);
```

I want to run this as script not inside a procedure.
I have 0 experience with PL/SQL so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155

Comment: @OldProgrammer how about the collection l, what is the analogous in PLSQL and how to add to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate the logic shown, but except in unusual circumstances I wouldn't recommend doing it that way. Collections are available and useful in PL/SQL, but printing them out is done by looping over the collection - so if all you're doing is collecting something in-memory to print it out, the better choice would be simply to print the items coming from the cursor when the cursor is iterated. In addition, doing a singleton SELECT inside a loop, where the data being selected in the inner SELECT is dependent on the outer SELECT, is equivalent to doing a JOIN - so do the join instead of pinging the database with a bunch of single-row SELECTs. Putting this together I suggest doing something like:

```
BEGIN
  FOR aRow in (SELECT t2.COL2
                 FROM TABLE1 t1
                 INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
                   ON t2.COL1 = t1.COL1
                 WHERE t1.WHATEVER = vSOMETHING_ELSE)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(aRow.COL2);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

In PL/SQL the best choice is generally to use a cursor to get the data in the form you want it, rather than collecting data and then iterating over the collection to transform it. Your data resides in the database - learn to work with it there.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want  a column in a table matching a column from another table, you won't need a loop, simply use `JOINS`

```
SELECT t2.col2
  FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
WHERE '<your_where_conditon>'
```

If you do want to display them using `dbms_output`, you may simply use an implicit cursor loop ( @Bob Jarvis answer) or `BULK COLLECT` to load into a collection.

```
DECLARE
TYPE col2type is TABLE OF table2.col2%TYPE;
col2_t col2type;
BEGIN
SELECT t2.col2 BULK COLLECT INTO col2_t
      FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
    WHERE '<your_where_conditon>';
for i in 1..col2_t.count 
loop
  dbms_output.put_line(col2_t(i).col2);
end loop;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet will solve your problem.

```
            set serveroutput on;
    declare
    type ty_tb_name is table of varchar2(20) index by pls_integer;
    l_tb_name ty_tb_name;
    cursor cur_acc_name is
    select account_name from cust_account;
    idx number := 1;
    begin
    for rec in cur_acc_name loop        
        l_tb_name(idx) := rec.account_name;
        idx := idx+1;
        exit when cur_acc_name%notfound;
    end loop;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('count:'||l_tb_name.count);
    for i in l_tb_name.first..l_tb_name.count loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('name:'||l_tb_name(i));
    end loop;

    exception
    when others then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(SQLERRM);
    end;
    /
```